# Unicode when using SNPP

Tags: excel, unicode, encoding

Have a program where my reps copy information from an excel spreadsheet and paste it into a site that sends pages to doctors pagers. When doctors receive it they are getting %09 for spacing between the fields. Is there a way to strip Unicode from excel? Without having to copy and paste into, say, a notepad document, and then repasting?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem have a problem with urlencoding rather than unicode.
You can look on [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) to learn about it.

I don't know which language your webinterface uses, but each has some function to convert it correctly.

BTW `%09` is an horizontal tabulation.